# how to draw a Direct2D transparent line in C++Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, direct2d

I'm using C++Builder XE4 with the VCL windows platform and I am using the wrapper TDirect2DCanvas to access the Direct2D functions. I'm porting GDI+ code to Direct2D and I'm stuck on how to draw a transparent line in Direct2D. When I say transparent I'm taking about having a line with some type of alpha-blend or transparent setting so the image under the line can be seen. The code below creates a Direct2D gradient brush and draws a line on the Direct2D render target but has no transparency. Can you show how to setup the Brush and/or Pen so the line draws transparent. Thanks

```cpp
// begin drawing
Canvas2D_->BeginDraw();
try
{
TColor clrs[] = {clRed, clLime};
// create a gradient brush
DelphiInterface<ID2D1Brush> pBrush =
Canvas->CreateBrush(clrs, 1,
D2D1::Point2F(-w/2, -h/2),
D2D1::Point2F(w/2, h/2));
Canvas->Brush->Handle = pBrush;

Canvas->Pen->Width = 10;
int x=25;
Canvas->MoveTo(x, -half_h);
Canvas->LineTo(x, half_h);

}
__finally
{
// end drawing (actual screen update)
Canvas2D_->EndDraw();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling ID2D1Brush::SetOpacity on the brush, with a value between 0.0 and 1.0 depending on how transparent you want the line:

```
DelphiInterface<ID2D1Brush> pBrush = // ...
pBrush->SetOpacity(0.5);
```

Comment: Setting the Brush->SetOpacity(0.5) only seems to effect filling objects like a polygon. It does not seem to effect the Pen so drawing a wide line is not transparent. Is there a way to set the Opacity for the Pen in Direct2D? 

This code runs but the Pen is not transparent
    Canvas->Pen->Width = 15;
    Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed;

    DelphiInterface<ID2D1Brush> pRedBrush =
    Canvas->CreateBrush(clRed);
    pRedBrush->SetOpacity(0.5);
    Canvas->Brush->Handle = pRedBrush;
    Canvas->Brush->Style = bsSolid;

    Canvas->MoveTo(x, y);
    Canvas->LineTo(x, y);

Comment: Sorry, I'm familiar with Direct2D but not with the TDirect2DCanvas wrapper that you're using. However I do know for a fact that setting an opacity on a brush does affect line drawing, if you use ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawLine. If the wrapper allows you to use the underlying ID2D1RenderTarget object, you can use its DrawLine method to get the desired effect.

Comment: Here is the answer. The object TDirect2DPen has its own Brush property. When you create the Brush you can assign it directly to the TDirect2DPen.Brush.Handle=TDirect2DPen.Brush. I did not know the pen had its own brush property. Once the brush is created with SetOpacity(0.5) the line is transparent.

Comment: `Canvas->Pen->Brush->Handle->SetOpacity(0.5);`